# Get all categories where at least one post has specific tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

**I'm not sure about the keyword to type to find articles related to my issue. Here is what I'm trying to achieve.**

Basically, I have several models :

`Category has_many Activity`

`Country has_many Activity`

then

`Activity belongs_to Category`

`Activity belongs_to Country`

Basically, `Activity` both has a `Category` and a `Country`.

I want to : `Get all Categories that have at least one activity with this specific Country`

Maybe I should change my data model... Please help

Comment: You need to define the data model as to how category relates to actiity and country relates to activity.

Comment: I edited, should be good now. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your models are like this:

```
class Category
  has_many :activities
end

class Country
  has_many :activities
end

class Activity
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :country
end
```

So you can get the categories using the relationship between Category and Activity, and Activity and Country:

```
Category.joins(activities: :country).where(countries: { name: <country_name> })
```

Comment: You are the champ ! I believe it was as simple as a table joint. Thanks sir !